# why does my car make a robot like noise?

Tags: dodge

It makes this noise every time im backing out of a parking spot as im turning the wheel. Not sure what it could be.

Comment: "Robot like noise" is not at all clear. Screech? Thump? Clank? Clatter? Ping? Click? Buzz? etc etc

Comment: I would guess the buzzing/winding sound that power steering makes sometimes...?

Comment: Does it have an electronically controlled parking brake?  It could be the brake disengaging.

Comment: @David its like a buzzing noise

Comment: Does the noise appear if you're moving forward? If you've set the parking brake? What if the car's not moving but the engine's running and you turn the steering wheel?

Comment: Could be the ABS pump test if it were a Honda, the Secondary Air Injection blower motor on a Cadillac, but if it's associated with turning the steering wheel it's likely low on power steering fluid.  Always helpful to know the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle you have questions about.

Comment: Check your power steering fluid level.